# Python Tabulate doesn't produce the correct table from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using  [Tabulate version 0.7.7](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate)  for Python 3.6

This is my code so far for a simple test using a dictionary.

```
from tabulate import tabulate

d = {"Dave":"13", "Bob":"15"}

headers = ["Name", "Age"]
print(tabulate(d, headers = headers))
```

The result I want is

```
Name    Age
------  -----
Dave    13
Bob     15
```

But what I am getting is

```
Name    Age
------  -----
1       1
3       5
```

Can someone help me please?

One question - Can I fix this using tabulate or should I be using a different python package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access `items` attribute of dict. Like this. It'll give you result you want.

```
>>> print(tabulate(d.items(), headers = headers))
Name      Age
------  -----
Bob        15
Dave       13
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

You need to give tabulate a list of tuples.  One way to do this with a dictionary is to use unpack the items like so:

```
from tabulate import tabulate

d = {"Dave":"13", "Bob":"15"}

headers = ["Name", "Age"]
print(tabulate(d.items(), headers = headers))
```

which returns

```
Name      Age
------  -----
Dave       13
Bob        15
```

Alternatively, you can use different lists and zip them together.  Tabulate is looking for inputs that look like this:

```
names = ['Dave','Bob']
ages = ['13','15']

d = zip(names,ages)

print(d)
```

which returns:

```
[('Dave', '13'), ('Bob', '15')]
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks very much! I will use the other solution in my development too!

Comment: No problem. The second method should help for having an arbitrary number of columns. Happy programming!